how to specify hidden import like 'from XXX import YYY as ZZZ' to pyInstaller?
dear all:
I have been trying to solve the problem of using pyinstaller for pyd files when the packaged EXE file cannot find some imports in the pyd files.
Then I found some suggestions of using --hidden-import option of pyinstaller.
Such options can also be specified the spec files for pyinstaller.
But such suggestions seem only dealing with simple import statements like
import XXX 

There is nowhere that I could find suggestions when more complex imports are used in python scripts.  For example:
import XXX as ZZZ
from XXX import YYY 
from XXX import YYY as ZZZ
from XXX import (YYY1, YYY2)

For such more complex import statements, how should I write the hidden import options?
Or how should I write the hiddenimports arguments in the spec file?
Thanks in advance.
